# A problem about open subgroup.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, local-field

How to prove:

When $F$ is a non-Archimedean local field.

then group $G = GL_n(F)$ is an open subset of $Mn(F)$?

The problem is from:

Let $n$ be an integer. The vector space $ F^n = F ×···× F $ carries the
product topology, relative to which it is a locally profinite group. As a special
case, the matrix ring $M_n(F)$ is a locally profinite group under addition, in
which multiplication of matrices is continuous.
The group $G = GL_n(F)$ is an open subset of $M_n(F)$; inversion of matrices
is continuous, so G is a topological group.

Which said  $G = GL_n(F)$ is an open subset of $M_n(F).$

$F$ is a non-Archimedean local field,and had proved $F $ as a additive group is a locally profinite group.

Thank you for sharing your idea!

Comment: What have you tried? For example, have you considered the determinant map $\mathrm{M}_n(F)\to F$?

Comment: I considered it ,but 1 is the closed set of $F$,so I think $GL_n(F)$ should be a closed set.

Comment: Can you prove it in the case where $F=\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I think \mathbb{R} may not be a local field.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is a local field, it's just not non-archimedian. But $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is not the pre-image of $1$ (that's $\mathrm{SL}_n$).... it's the elements whose determinant is not $0$.

Comment: Sorry,I got them mixed up, Thanks for your answer.